# Makefile and compiling issue; not declared in scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, makefile, header

I'm not sure where most of my problems that cause this not to compile are coming from. I'm relatively new to this though, so it's probably obvious where I went wrong to others. This part of a project simulating placing cards information in a linked list, but having the code work correctly is something I can do myself. I just cannot figure out why I cannot get it to compile with the makefile, nor where the errors such as "head not declared in this scope" come from.

Edited to update code with recent changes & add compiler errors

proj3.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "tsllist.h"
#include "card.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declaration of Variables
    TSLList<Card> myList;
    int elementSuit;
    int elementFace;
    char elementThree;
    
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open ("cards.txt");

    inFile >> elementSuit; //Read in 1st element
    inFile >> elementFace; //Read in 2nd elemen
    Card myCard(elementFace, elementSuit);
    inFile >> elementThree; //Read in 3rd element
    while(!inFile.eof()){
        if (inFile.eof()) break;
        switch(elementThree){
            case 'a' :
                myList.insertInOrder(myCard);
                myList.printAll();
                break;
            case 'd' :
                myList.deleteVal(myCard);
                myList.printAll();
                break;
            case 'D':
                myList.deleteAllVal(myCard);
                myList.printAll();
                break;
            default:
                break;
                
        }
        inFile >> elementSuit; //Read in 1st element
        inFile >> elementFace; //Read in 2nd elemen
        inFile >> elementThree; //Read in 3rd element
        Card myCard(elementFace, elementSuit);
    }   
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

tsllist.h

```
#ifndef TS_LINKED_LIST_H
#define TS_LINKED_LIST_H

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class TSLList {
    public:

        // Constructor
        TSLList() {
            head = nullptr;
        }
        
        //D Destructor
        ~TSLList() {
            //clearList();
            TSLLNode *tmp = head;
            while(tmp != nullptr)
            {
                //will delete each node pointed to by head 
                //and prints when doing so
                head = head->next;
                tmp->next = nullptr; 
                cout << "Deleting " << tmp << endl;
                delete tmp; 
                tmp = head; 
            }
        }
        
        // prints the info content and address of each node in the list
        void printAll() const {
            for (TSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->next)
                std::cout << "->[" << tmp->info << "," << tmp << "]";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    
        // Inserts node in ascending order
        void insertInOrder(T val) {
            TSLLNode *prev; // for previous node when parsing
            TSLLNode *tmp; //pointer for current node when parsing list
            TSLLNode *newNode = new TSLLNode;
            newNode->info = val;
            newNode->next = nullptr;

            if(head==nullptr)
            {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else if(newNode->info <= head->info) //
            {
                newNode->next = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = head;
                prev = nullptr;
                while(tmp != nullptr && tmp->info < newNode->info)
                {
                    prev = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                prev->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = tmp;
        }
        
        // Deletes an occurrence of argument
        template <class T> T deleteVal(T val) {
            TSLLNode *tmp;
            TSLLNode *prev;
            if(!head)
                return val;
            if(head->info == val)
            {
                tmp=head->next;
                delete head;
                head = tmp;
                return val;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = head;
                while(tmp != nullptr && tmp->info != val)
                {
                    prev = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
                if(tmp)
                {
                    prev->next = tmp->next;
                    delete tmp;
                    return val;
                }
            }
        }
        // Deletes all occurrences of argument
        void deleteAllVal(T val) {
            TSLLNode *tmp=head;
            TSLLNode *prev=head;
            while(tmp!=nullptr)
            {
                if(tmp->info == val)
                {
                    if(tmp==head)
                    {
                        head = tmp->next;
                        delete tmp;
                        tmp = head;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prev->next = tmp->next;
                        delete tmp;
                        tmp = prev->next;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp->next;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        
        // Clears the list (deallocates memory)
        //void TSLList::clearList() {
            //TSLLNode *tmp = head;
        //  while(tmp != nullptr)
        //  {
                //will delete each node pointed to by head 
                //and prints when doing so
        //      head = head->next;
        //      tmp->next = nullptr; 
        //      std::cout << "Deleting " << tmp << std::endl;
        //      delete tmp; 
        //      tmp = head; 
        //  }
    //  }
    private:
        //Node stored in linked list
        struct TSLLNode {
                TSLLNode(T el = T()) {
                    info = el;
                next = nullptr;
             }
                int info;
                TSLLNode *next;
            };
        
                TSLLNode *head; // head of the list
};

#endif
```

makefile

```
## compiler
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -pedantic -g

proj3: proj3.o card.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) proj3.o card.o -o proj3

NumberList.o: card.cpp card.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c card.cpp

proj3.o: proj3.cpp card.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c proj3.cpp
clean:
    $(RM) proj3 *.o
```

makefile/compiler errors

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -g -c proj3.cpp
In file included from proj3.cpp:9:0:
card.h:5:12: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
 using std::ostream;
            ^~~~~~~
proj3.cpp:11:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘namespace’
 using namespace std;
       ^~~~~~~~~
proj3.cpp:54:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 }
 ^
In file included from proj3.cpp:8:0:
tsllist.h: In constructor ‘TSLList<T>::TSLList()’:
tsllist.h:22:4: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
    head = nullptr;
    ^~~~
tsllist.h: In destructor ‘TSLList<T>::~TSLList()’:
tsllist.h:28:8: error: ‘TSLLNode’ was not declared in this scope
        TSLLNode *tmp = head;
        ^~~~~~~~
tsllist.h:28:18: error: ‘tmp’ was not declared in this scope
        TSLLNode *tmp = head;
                  ^~~
tsllist.h:28:24: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
        TSLLNode *tmp = head;
                        ^~~~
tsllist.h: In member function ‘void TSLList<T>::printAll() const’:
tsllist.h:43:9: error: ‘TSLLNode’ was not declared in this scope
    for (TSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->next)
         ^~~~~~~~
tsllist.h:43:19: error: ‘tmp’ was not declared in this scope
    for (TSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->next)
                   ^~~
tsllist.h:43:25: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
    for (TSLLNode *tmp = head; tmp != nullptr; tmp = tmp->next)
                         ^~~~
tsllist.h: In member function ‘void TSLList<T>::insertInOrder(T)’:
tsllist.h:50:4: error: ‘TSLLNode’ was not declared in this scope
    TSLLNode *prev; // for previous node when parsing
    ^~~~~~~~
tsllist.h:51:14: error: ‘tmp’ was not declared in this scope
    TSLLNode *tmp; //pointer for current node when parsing list
              ^~~
tsllist.h:52:14: error: ‘newNode’ was not declared in this scope
    TSLLNode *newNode = new TSLLNode;
              ^~~~~~~
tsllist.h:52:28: error: ‘TSLLNode’ does not name a type
    TSLLNode *newNode = new TSLLNode;
                            ^~~~~~~~
tsllist.h:56:7: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
    if(head==nullptr)
       ^~~~
tsllist.h:74:9: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
     prev->next = newNode;
         ^~
tsllist.h:74:9: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
tsllist.h:79:3: error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
   template <class T> T deleteVal(T val) {
   ^~~~~~~~
tsllist.h:151:2: error: expected primary-expression before ‘private’
  private:
  ^~~~~~~
tsllist.h:162:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
                 TSLLNode<T> *head; // head of the list
                           ^
tsllist.h:162:30: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
                 TSLLNode<T> *head; // head of the list
                              ^~~~
proj3.cpp: At global scope:
proj3.cpp:54:1: error: expected ‘;’ at end of input
 }
 ^
makefile:12: recipe for target 'proj3.o' failed
make: *** [proj3.o] Error 1
```

card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

// Enumerated type that represents the card suits
enum suit {diamonds, clubs, hearts, spades, joker};

class Card
{
public:
    //default constructor - creates Joker card by calling 2-parameter constructor
    Card() : Card(-1, joker) {};

    //constructor that takes a card's face value (an integer) and its suit
    // card face values: Ace=0, 2=1, 3=2, ... Q=11, K=12
    Card (int, suit);

    // compare and return true if face value of *this is less than that of cd, false otherwise
    bool operator<(const Card& cd) const;

    // compare and return true if face value of *this is greater than that of cd, false otherwise
    bool operator>(const Card& cd) const;

    // compare and return true if face value of *this is less than or equal to that of cd, false otherwise
    bool operator<=(const Card& cd) const;

    // compare and return true if face value of *this is greater than or equal to that of cd, false otherwise
    bool operator>=(const Card& cd) const;

    // compare and return true if *this has the same face value as cd, false otherwise
    bool operator==(const Card& cd) const;

    // compare and return true if *this has the a different face value than cd, false otherwise
    bool operator!=(const Card& cd) const;

    // declare ostream << a friend of this class and overload << operator to display card
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Card& cd)
    {
        switch (cd.cardFace)
        {
            case 10:
                os <<"J";
                break;
            case 11:
                os <<"Q";
                break;
            case 12:
                os <<"K" ;
                break;
            case 0:
                os <<"A" ;
                break;
            case -1:
                os <<"j" ;
                break;
            default:
                os << cd.cardFace + 1;
        }
        switch (cd.cardSuit)
        {
            case 0: 
                os << "D";
                break;
            case 1 : 
                os << "C";
                break;
            case 2: 
                os << "H";
                break;
            case 3: 
                os << "S";
                break;
            case 4: 
                os << "*";
                break;
        }
    
        os << "[" << cd.pointValue << "]";
        return os;
    }
 

private:
    suit cardSuit;      // card's suit
    int cardFace;         // card's face value
    int pointValue;     // card's point value (from its face)
};
#endif
```

card.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"card.h"
using namespace std;

//constructor that takes a card's face value (an integer) and its suit
// card face values: Ace=0, 2=1, 3=2, ... Q=11, K=12
Card::Card (int x, suit y)
{
    cardFace = x;
    cardSuit = y;
}

//compare and return true if face value of *this is less than that of cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator<(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace<cd.cardFace;
}

// compare and return true if face value of *this is greater than that of cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator>(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace>cd.cardFace;
}

// compare and return true if face value of *this is less than or equal to that of cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator<=(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace<=cd.cardFace;
}

// compare and return true if face value of *this is greater than or equal to that of cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator>=(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace>=cd.cardFace;
}

// compare and return true if *this has the same face value as cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator==(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace==cd.cardFace;
}

// compare and return true if *this has the a different face value than cd, false otherwise
bool Card::operator!=(const Card& cd) const
{
    return cardFace!=cd.cardFace;
}
```

Comment: If you're getting compile errors please show them (cut and paste, properly formatted).  Don't forget to show the compile line that caused the errors to be generated.  Without seeing the actual problem that we can't help at all.

Comment: I will point out that your rule for `card.o` for some reason uses a target name of `NumberList.o`.  I can't know if that's the problem, without seeing the compile line and error messages.

Comment: I'm certain it's not the latter, as it compiles when all the references to and uses of tsllist.h are removed/ commented out.

Comment: Well, you should start with the first error (not the last one!  The later the error is the more likely it is to be caused by some earlier error).  It says there's something wrong with your `card.h` file at line 5.  You haven't shown us this file or what the first 5 lines contain.  I will say that I personally think it's a very bad idea to put `using` into header files like that.  It can have serious consequences (`using` doesn't stop at the end of the file!!) for files that are included.  You should just write out the references: it's more clear and not that much more effort.

Comment: I put the card h and cpp files up again. Now I will say that almost everything in the .h file was done by the instructor and I'm really not supposed to change it (hence I focused on the issues with tsllist.h, which is mine).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your `tlslist.h` file.  You are missing a close brace for the if-statement in your `insertInOrder()` method:

```
    // Inserts node in ascending order
    void insertInOrder(T val) {
      ...
        if(head==nullptr)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if(newNode->info <= head->info) //
        {
            newNode->next = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = head;
            prev = nullptr;
            while(tmp != nullptr && tmp->info < newNode->info)
            {
                prev = tmp;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            prev->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = tmp;
---> Need } here
    }
```

Because of these mismatched braces this template is not ended, and the content of the `cards.h` file is being included inside your template which is illegal syntax.

You should try to find an IDE which will warn you about things like mismatched braces etc. automatically: most will.

Comment: Wow thanks! I wish I had noticed that myself, not sure I'll be able to fix the new errors that cropped up before it's too late :/